# Html Tables : Inserting data

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following source code for table requirement. I want to insert the data from the beginning of the table, but I am unable to do so as it starts from the exact middle of the table. How to enter the data such that I can start from the beginning. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Title</title>
<table style="width: 665px; height: 589px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 49px;">
<td style="width: 664px; height: 49px;" colspan="2"><img src="#">
<p align="right"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google it!</a></p> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 117px;">
<td style="width: 223.85px; height: 117px;">A</td>
<td style="width: 440.15px; height: 117px;">B</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 120px;">
<td style="width: 223.85px; height: 120px;">C</td>
<td style="width: 440.15px; height: 244px;" rowspan="2">D</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 124px;">
<td style="width: 223.85px; height: 124px;">E</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 173px;">
<td style="width: 223.85px; height: 173px;">F</td>
<td style="width: 440.15px; height: 173px;">G</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And I would like to resize the columns based on their text but in my case, it automatically resizes when one increase. How to create split these two columns in my case?

Comment: you are talking about text in cell, right?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/ejxazd6u/

Comment: Yeah the text @Leothelion

Comment: Thanks @Leothelion But "I would like to resize the columns based on their text but in my case, it automatically resizes when one increase. How to create split these two coulmns in my case?"

Comment: Its table man so if one cell will increase the whole row will increase. Better use div or span. or fix width.

Comment: or show me the image of your desired output. Can try to help.

Comment: I just want to split these two columns but as a whole it should be fit in a single table

Comment: two columns means A,C,E,F and B,D,G right? use div then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109760/discussion-between-highlander141-and-leo-the-lion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your data in top of the cell then use `vertical-align:top;`

In your table, for all td use this :

```
td{vertical-align: top;}
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/ejxazd6u/)